# Remove Location circle from Maps

Tags: macos

Maps on OS X 10.10 has an annoying blue circle (around current location?) which obscures the detail you are trying to view. How can I turn it off

Comment: Want more details ? Just zoom !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler That just replaces the circle by a blue transparent circle of the same size

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by disabling access to your location for the Maps app.

This is done in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy**.

Select **Location Services** in the left panel and make sure **Maps** is unchecked in the list of apps allowed to use your location. This should remove the Current Location marker from the app without disrupting your access to the internet or preventing other apps using your location.

[image: OS X System Preferences: Security & Privacy Screen]

Answer (score 0):

The blue circle is apparently where `Maps` thinks the WiFi I am using is located. Turning WiFi off removes the circle, allowing the image to be viewed.

This may require another (Ethernet) connection to view images.